# What is the replacement of alert() helper function in Sweetalert v2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I'm using Sweetalert v2 with Laravel and because I had experience with Sweetalert v1, I knew that in the Controller method, I can do something like this:

```
public function update(Request $request, User $user)
{
    ...

    alert()->success('Process is done');
}
```

But for Sweetalert 2 I get this error:

**Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\Admin\alert()**

So how can I properly call a popup message in the Controller method when using Sweetalert v2?

Comment: There is a [Laravel SweetAlert](https://github.com/realrashid/sweet-alert) package that provides a nice interface for working with SweetAlert and provides a similar API that you're familiar with.

Comment: @Peppermintology You mean I have to remove this Sweetalert v2 and install a new one?

Comment: try to run composer dump-autoload

Comment: The package includes the required SweetAlert JS libraries as part of the installation process when you publish the assets so you don't need to manually include it yourself. Therefore if you have added SweetAlert via npm, you should be OK to remove it. Have a read through the [Laravel SweetAlert documentation](https://realrashid.github.io/sweet-alert/install).